# Using ajax to run a php file and output php on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a PHP file with ajax and have text output from the PHP file into my container. I've looked into multiple examples but still don't get anything out of my ListTranslations.php file.

A short explanation of what is supposed to happen:

On index.php file, I run a list of all languages found in the database and fill `onClick` function with a specific language. On click, the ajax function should run my ListTranslations.php file and output the list of all the translations found for the specific language.

Here is the index.php where the ajax function is called:

```
foreach($languages as $language){
  echo '<a href="index.php?id='. $language . '"target="_self" onclick="sendLanguage(\'' .$language. '\')">' . $language . '</a>' .  ': ' . count($language) . "<br>";
}
```

ajax function: ( I have a content div set )

```
function sendLanguage(tongue) {
   jQuery.ajax({
   url: "ListTranslations.php",
   method: 'GET',
   data: {language: tongue},
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(r){
     $('#content').html(response);
  }).fail(function(e){
     console.log(e);
  });
}
```

ListTranslations.php file:

```
 if($_GET["tongue"]) {
    $aPoem = $poems->find(array('language'=>($_GET["tongue"])));
    foreach($aPoem as $poem) {
        echo '<a href="testi.php?id=' . $poem["_id"] . '" target="_self">' . $poem["title"] .'</a><br>';
    }
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and why it is not working so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're selector `$('content')` doesn't look like it would find anything

Comment: In the ajax function should not be apostrophes on the line of data around tongue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, declare if your div is of a class or id content:

```
$(".content");
$("#content");
```

Also, your function argument isn't used in the whole structure and you use only 'tongue' string; to pass a variable, get rid of '' like:

```
data: { language: tongue }
```

Also, any particular reason to use **deprecated** jQuery methods? If not, you should use this structure:

```
function findDifferentNameThanAjax(tongue) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "ListTranslations.php",
    method: 'GET',
    data: {language: tongue},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(r){
    $('#content').html(response);
  }).fail(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

Alse, make sure if your ajax url is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like I had looked at some old tutorials and that's why I had the deprecated methods. Still doesn't seem to work tho. Might be a problem with the foreach.. Will update the code to what I have now.

Comment: I'm getting a responseText to console when trying to echo a string from ListTranslations.php but nothing from my foreach. Is there a different syntax for handling foreach or objects?

Comment: it is not tongue you $_GET, but $_GET['language']. What you should try is to print_r all the $_REQUEST for yourself and then work your way down the object.

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks. Now after fixing that it's giving me an error: Fatal Error. Call to a member function. If I take the foreach loop out of the If() phrases I'm getting: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Getting interesting...